# Cordova SQLite class - cannot return value from database

Tags: sqlite, cordova

So, I'm building an app with Cordova and SQLite and below is the object Storage I created to handle the database properties and methods.

```js
function Storage(connection, platform)
{
    if (platform == 'mobile') {
        this.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: connection.name, location: connection.location});
    } else if (platform == 'web') {
        this.db = window.openDatabase(connection.name, connection.version, connection.mode, -1);
    }

    this.read = function(sql, vals) {
        var rows = null;

        this.db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(sql, vals, function(tx, res) {
                rows = res.rows;
            });
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('Transaction error: '+error.message);
        });

        return rows;
    };
};

var connection = {
    name: 'database.db',
    version: '1.0',
    mode: 'Development'
};

var db = new Storage(connection, 'web');

var sql = '';
sql += 'SELECT *';
sql += ' FROM countdown';
sql += ' WHERE countdown_status != ?;';
var rows = db.read(sql, [1]);
console.log(rows);
```

This code logs 'null' and I don't know why since I have data into my database. And when I try to log from within the tx.executeSql method, it logs the data from database.

Any ideas on why I cannot get this data out of that function?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

the db read is asynchronous - it needs to return the data to a callback function like so:

```
 getHighScore: function (type,callback) {

  var query = "SELECT Value FROM HighScore where Type = '" + type + "';";

playedDb.transaction(function (tx) {

 tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, res) {
     var out;

     if (typeof res.rows.item(0) === "undefined") {
         if (typeof callback === "function") {
           callback(-1);
           return;
         };
     } else {
         out = res.rows.item(0).Value

         //task 301 only allow alphanumeric and decimal point (for version)
         out = String(out).replace(/[^0-9a-z\.]/gi, '');

         if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback(out);
            return;
         };
     }

 }, function (e) {
     console.log("getHighScore FAILED: " + e.message);
     if (typeof callback === "function") {
         callback(-2);
         return;
     };
 });
```